# Backslash and final quote

Tags: c++, c, windows

Question is: why final backslash in argv arguments are interpreted as escape-backslash, not as backslash `'\\'` itself So code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (NumArgs > 1)
        std::cout << pArgsArray[1] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`Program.exe "C:\Dir\"`

expected output: `C:\Dir`

real output `C:\Dir"`

so why final backslash is not interpreted `as-is` like othes backslahes??

same result we obviosly get in C#

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with C, so why are you using that tag? (C doesn't have iostream.h, and definitely doesn't support std.cout, unless it's changed drastically recently and I was asleep and missed it.) It also has nothing to do with .net (you've covered that with C#.) Please use only the tags that are actually relevant to your question; it makes a difference for future readers searching this site for answers to their own questions.

Comment: @KenWhite: I've put the C tag back in because the behaviour in question is in the C runtime library and therefore is common to both C and C++.

Comment: I've checked that and the backslash only disappears when putting in quote. When you run `Program.exe C:\Dir\ ` it result exactly the argument passed. The behavior doesn't appear using a `*.bat` file either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command-line escapes in `cmd` are downright crazy. Spaces, pipe characters etc. are escaped with a caret: `^`. Quotes are escaped with a backslash: `\`. A backslash which doesn't immediatly precede a quote is taken literally.

I don't know if there's a way to end a quoted argument with a backslash. Maybe doubling the backslash could help. Some sources also suggest `^\` to escape such a backslash.